# Include JSP file with Java

Tags: java, jsp

I know that including and external file in jsp can be done with something like this:

```
<%@ include file="banner.jsp" %>
```

But is there a way of doing this inside a java class/object?

Comment: You want to include jsp in java clsas ?????????????

Comment: @Jigar Joshi: including a jsp view from a Servlet is a perfectly reasonable thing to do.

Comment: @Jigar: Ordinarily I would mock you for those question marks, but in this case I feel you were justified :)

Comment: Note that the `@include` is not able to include external files. The file has got to be in the same webcontent in order for it to work.

Comment: To further @BalusC's comment, `<c:import>` from the JSTL *is* able to include external files, so you can use that instead.

Comment: what exactly is your ultimate goal with this?

Comment: Like @BalusC's said <c:import> is probably enough for what you seem to need 
if you want more info about it check this page (or by a man and google it...)
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v5r6/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.commerce.developer.doc/refs/rsdjspbpinclude.htm

Answer (score 5):

You can do it inside a servlet (or any class having access to the current request), via the [`RequestDispatcher`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html):

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/banner.jsp").include(request, response);
```

Note that you should rarely need to do this. It would mean that you are outputting view content from a servlet, and you should do that mainly in a jsp.

Comment: That's correct, but note that this is not the best practice. Inclucing other servlet in a servlet makes sense, but including a JSP in a servlet makes little sense. You'd rather forward the request/response to a JSP which in turn includes other JSP.

Comment: @BalusC - I just added that note.

Comment: @BalusC and @Bozho: I have found that when I use `forward()` instead of `include()`, the resultant jsp page loses the context of the client's original request and if I try to use the request object within the jsp page to construct absolute urls, I get the jsp page's url instead of what the client requested. I ran into this issue a while back while building a mail-this-link-to-a-friend feature.

Comment: @Asaph: There are other ways for that.

Comment: @BalusC: What is the preferred way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

In Servlet you can call:

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("include.jsp");
rd.include(request, response);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is NO way to do:

```
<%@ include file="banner.jsp" %>
```

in java, because - as you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580120/whats-the-difference-between-including-files-with-jsp-include-directive-jsp-in) that is a static jsp include, which is done at JSP compile time,
I wish there was such a thing as static code includes in java.