# Elements in <jsp:include> doesn't have access to form element in parent jsp

Tags: forms, jsp

I have a Parent Jsp called Details.jsp.
That have a form tag and some buttons like submit.

Since my page have different sections so I have created several jsps by breaking down the page.

section1.jsp,

section2.jsp.

But now. I dont have access to the form that is defined in parent jsp and the Jsp is giving error.

FYI : I am using custom tags in the child jsps (section1.jsp)

Do you have any idea what could be cause ?

Thanks,
Rajan

Comment: To fix the issue please share some piece of relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at this other post [What's the difference between including files with JSP include directive, JSP include action and using JSP Tag Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580120/whats-the-difference-between-including-files-with-jsp-include-directive-jsp-in) for more detailed explainations.

I think that what you want is really an `@include`, as it will include the source of the included jsp instead of running it in its own context.