# Including Javascript code from a JSP file

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, jsp-tags

I have a JSP file that gives me a bunch of JS code that I need to put in my view page (particularly in my JSP file that is the view for the current URL. Using Spring MVC) . Is there a way for it?

I have already tried a bunch of suggestions from here: [Including JSP code from another JSP file correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28680262/including-jsp-code-from-another-jsp-file-correctly) and here https://coderanch.com/t/596663/frameworks/Calling-jsp-include-tag-javascript but none gives clear answer on it. When the view is rendered after hitting the controller it just gave a plain JS code in the window instead of embedding it as JS code.

```
    <html>
    <head> </head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <jsp:include page="./myJSPfiles/MyJSPfileforScript" />
    </script>
</html>
```

As I said, it just gives plain JS code in the browser instead of embedding it. I am fairly new to JSPs in general. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post your jsp code as well ?

Comment: The above mentioned code is jsp code itself.

Comment: No , i mean to say the `jsp` page you have included .

Answer (score 0):

Use something like below line of code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/index.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am able to access my file by simply using its path( as in code above) , the problem is that JS code provider is not a JS file but a JSP one