# sharing part of a jsp file for multiple pages

Tags: jsp, http, servlets

I have a part of a jsp page with a bar containing multiple pictures, buttons and text, which I want to be the same on some multiple other pages too. How can I achieve it without "copy paste" of the elements and their functionality?

Comment: You can use "<jsp:include>" tag A brief explanation in the accepted answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580120/whats-the-difference-between-including-files-with-jsp-include-directive-jsp-in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you could use `<jsp:include>`

But do take a look at [Apache tiles](https://tiles.apache.org/framework/index.html). This framework allows you to bundle multiple jsp fragments into a page layout.