# jsp:include vs %@include for %@taglib functionality

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jspinclude

I am using NetBeans 8.1 with the Spring framework and have stumbled on something I do not understand in relation too jsp:include and %@include and how it effects the availability or functionality of %@taglib entries.

I have this line at the top of my layout jsp that then includes my views.

```
 <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

I am using this line to include my views to allow a layout to be used with more than on view.

```
  <jsp:include page="../views/${pa}.jsp"/>
```

In the view jsp I have the following code retrieving data from the database to create a drop down.

```
 <% List r = new com.mycompany.dbobjects.javaobject().main();%>
 <c:set var="n" value="<%=r%>"/>       
 <c:forEach items="${n}" var="item">
     <c:out value="${item.getID()}"/>
     <c:out value="${item.getName()}"/> 
 </c:forEach>
```

In order to get the data to appear using the jsp:include I have to add this line to the top of the view.

```
 <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

If I use a %@include and hard code the view name I do not need to put the %@taglib at the top of the view. Being new to JSP and Java I do not understand why the two includes change the placement of the %@taglib line.

Comment: Have looked at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580120/whats-the-difference-between-including-files-with-jsp-include-directive-jsp-in?

Comment: Perfect.  I did not see that one. Apparently I was not searching for the right terminology.