# How to access the pagecontext of the parent JSP in the child jsp that is loaded in an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, iframe

I have a parent JSP that has widgets created using custom JSTL tags.
To improve the page loading, I have used Jquery to dynamically load these widgets into Iframes. The source for the iframes is the widget code in separate JSP files.

So I created a JSP for each widget

```
$(function () {
           var widgetSrc = ["frame1.jsp", "frame2.jsp", "frame3.jsp", "frame4.jsp", "frame5.jsp", "frame6.jsp","frame7.jsp"];

       $.each(widgetSrc, function (index, element) {              
           var res = element.split(".");               
           var container = $("#"+res[0]);              
           appendNew(container, element);                  
       })
   })
```

Now in one of the widgets I need to access the HttpRequestrequest object to get few parameters.

In the parent jsp

`<%= pageContext.findAttribute("sortBy") %>` is giving the parameter value

in the frame1.jsp

`<%= pageContext.findAttribute("sortBy") %>` is always giving null

Please suggest how to pass the request object or the pagecontext of the parent.jsp to frame.jsp

Thanks in advance

Comment: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

1. `pageContext` is not request scope. It's page scope. Try `<%=request.getParameter("sortBy")%>` if the normal `${sortBy}` or `${requestScope.sortBy}` don't work.
2. I expect iframes to have a different request scope.

You would be able to load the widget by `jsp:include`. If you need additional data than what already is set in request scope, you can use params.

```
<c:set var = "myWidget" value = "widget1"/>
<jsp:include page="${myWidget}.jsp" flush="true">
    <jsp:param name="sortBy" value="abc"/>
    <jsp:param name="myAttribute2" value="value2"/>
</jsp:include>
```

Note that you still won't find the attributes in `pageContext`, as you include a `page` with its own `pageContext`.

Here you can find a list of [mechanisms to include content in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14763794/5507619).