# java- Possible to import a jspf file?

Tags: java

I have a java class in a different module that the jspf file is located.In a normal JSP file, I would import it this way:

```
<%@include file="../../../WEB-INF/jspf/corelib.jspf" %>
```

Right now,I want the equivalent of this in my `.java` class but can't find a proper way to import.

How would I import this?

Comment: This may be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624911/include-jsp-file-with-java see Bozho's answer

Comment: I need to get `initialcontext` from it that's why